# Generalized Regression Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, regression, data-science-model

I do not understand Generalized Regression. What is the purpose of the Neural Networks structure? And how does it works?

Comment: Any reference to where you read that? You need to give more context and be more specific about what you do not understand.

Comment: @n1k31t4 Yes, you are right, I apologize. I do not know the mathematical balance of Grnn's layers. I searched for an example, but I did not find it in a very good shape. Could you tell GRNN over an example?

Comment: Can you add a diagram or something to make it clearer what you are asking?